# how to set title in a for-loop using vue.js in this example?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
  <template v-for="item in job">
    <tr>
        <td v-for="i in item.stage" :style="getStyle(i.status.name)" title="[[ i.node.name ]]" >
          <b>[[ i.node.name ]]</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
```

I am trying to set the title for each td - but instead the title is literally being set to [[ i.node.name ]] as string rather than the value.

note:  **[[ i.node.name ]]**  prints the value so I know it is correct, I must be using wrong syntax for the title though.

also side note: I'm using [[ ]] as delimiters in vue.js

Comment: It's `{{ }}` not square brackets.

Comment: I am using [[ ]] delimiters though

Comment: you cant, see the documentation here:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text
Remember you are interpolating data into a template it's not vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the brackets from your title and add a colon `:` in front of the title. Take a look at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

```
  <template v-for="item in job">
        <tr>
            <td v-for="i in item.stage" :style="getStyle(i.status.name)" :title="i.node.name" >
              <b>[[ i.node.name ]]</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
```